# Numerically decomposing a function as a sum of non-integer powers

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a function of $x\in(0,1)$ that I can compute numerically. I expect that there exists a convergent decomposition of the type
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{\Delta_n} 
$$
for some real numbers $a_n$ and $\Delta_0 < \Delta_1 < \Delta_2 < \cdots$.
How can I numerically determine $\Delta_0,\cdots,\Delta_N$?

Comment: Can you explain why you are interested in this problem?

Comment: A sketch of an approach: For small $x$ we have $f(x)\approx a_0 x^{\Delta_0}$. So you can take the logarithm and polyfit. Then you can consider $f(x)-a_0x^{\Delta_0}$ and iterate the process.

Comment: The problem is interesting in conformal field theory, where four-point correlation functions behave as my function $f(x)$. The values $\{\Delta_n\}$ essentially determine the space of states of the theory. In my case I can compute $f(x)$ by summing an expansion in powers of $1-x$, and I need to decompose it into powers of $x$.

Comment: In my experience the small $x$ behaviour does not give a good precision for $\Delta_0$, let alone higher $\Delta_n$. This may be because my numerical determination of $f(x)$ becomes less precise near $x=0$.

Comment: Can you post that "expansion in powers of $(1-x)$"? If it is good enough, there is a chance that the answer may be given in terms of its coefficients directly without passing through any computations of $f(x)$, which would be certainly better from any standpoint.

Comment: The expansion in powers of $(1-x)$ is a sum of infinitely many Virasoro conformal blocks, and such blocks are complicated. They can be computed numerically, with a very fast convergence if $x$ is close to $1$.

Comment: But, at least, the powers of $(1-x)$ are integer and you can compute the coefficients reasonably fast with high precision, right?

Comment: More precisely, I have $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-x)^{\Delta'_n} \sum_{m=0}^\infty c'_{nm}(1-x)^m$ where the index $n$ labels the contributions of a conformal block. Each block is a sum of integer powers whose coefficients $c'_{nm}$ can be computed reasonably fast. But each block comes with a prefactor that in general involves a non-integer power $\Delta'_n$ of $(1-x)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the fine details of behaviour near $x=0$ are essential for determining the $\Delta_n$.  If you can only compute finitely many values numerically, the computed values will always fit a polynomial.

Comment: However that polynomial will have unnecessarily large coefficients, which might be enough to raise the red flag and to change the exponents a bit. The next stupid question on my part: do we expect $\Delta_n$ to be separated from each other by some reasonable amounts? Also, can $a_n$ be both positive and negative?

Comment: The coefficients $a_n$ can be both positive and negative. For the values of $\Delta_n$, there are two possibilities: either they belong to $F+\mathbb{N}$ where $F$ is a finite set and $\mathbb{N}$ are positive integers, or they belong to $I+\mathbb{N}$ where $I$ is an infinite set of the type $I=i_1\mathbb{N}+i_2\mathbb{N}$ with $i_1$ and $i_2$ positive, in general irrational numbres.

Comment: But these two possibilities for the values of $\Delta_n$ are only plausible guesses. What is sure is that $\Delta_{n+1}-\Delta_n$ is not always bounded from below, and that if $\Delta$ occurs, then so do the elements of $\Delta +\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The last question before I try the thing I have in mind: I hope that $\Delta_n'$ and $c_{nm}'$ are nice rational numbers, so you can compute with any precision you want (for what I want to suggest, this may be crucial, especially the $c'_{nm}$ part). BTW, you don't expect each block to be of that same type, do you?

Comment: $\Delta'_n$ are simple (known explicitly), but $c'_{nm}$ have to be computed numerically, and with my current code the precision is about $10$ digits for the first few coefficients. So overall $f(x)$ is known to about $10$ significant digits up to about $x=.01$, for smaller $x$ the precision decreases. Each block is of the same type, blocks differ only by the values of $\Delta'_n$ and $c'_{nm}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% on this (forget where I read it) but fractional calculus can deal with this problem. This is too long to post as a comment but I think it might help.

If we take the Riemann-Liouville operator $D^{a}$ that satisfies $D^a x^b = \frac{\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(b-a+1)}x^{b-a}$ it gives $D^{\Delta_0}f(x)\Big{|}_{x=0} = \Gamma(\Delta_0 + 1)a_0$. To solve $a_1$ just take $D^{\Delta_1}(f(x) - a_0x^{\Delta_0}) \Big{|}_{x=0}$, and iterating

$$\Gamma(\Delta_n + 1)a_n = D^{\Delta_n} (f(x) - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_jx^{\Delta_j})\Big{|}_{x=0}$$

Now you have to know $\Delta_n$, and that the expansion exists, but this solution should work. To find the operator $D^a$ just google Riemann-Liouville Differintegral.

Comment: If I knew $\Delta_n$ I could find $a_n$ by solving the linear system $f(x_i) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n x_i^{\Delta_n}$ for $N$ randomly chosen positions $x_i$. The difficult part is to find $\Delta_n$.